# data в haskell? как мне создать объект с применением типов Objekt, Art и Inventar

Tags: дата, теория-типов

```
data Objekt = Objekt Art Gewicht Preis
  deriving(Eq,Show)
data Art = Pistole | Tagebuch | Smartphone | Medipack | Fackel
  deriving(Eq,Show)
type Gewicht = Float
type Preis   = Float

data Inventar = Inventar [Objekt]
  deriving(Eq,Show)
```

мой имеющийся инвентарь я написала просто в списках...но это я думаю не правильно...что мне делать...?

```
--Inventar = [2, Pistolen, 710.0, 395.00]
--Inventar = [1, Tagebuch, 450, 30.99]
--Inventar = [1, Smartphone, 360, 140.00]
--Inventar = [2, Mediapacks, 350, 6.99]
--Inventar = [2, Fakeln, 857.00, 2.99]**
```

Answer (score 0):

В правой части объявления `data` следует перечисление конструкторов алгебраического типа данных, например, `Objekt`, `Smartphone` или `Inventar`. Их необходимо указывать при создании экземпляра:

```
objekt1 :: Objekt
objekt1 = Objekt Pistolen 710.0 395.00

objekt2 :: Objekt
objekt2 = Objekt Tagebuch 450 30.99

inventar :: Inventar
inventar = Inventar [objekt1, objekt2]
```

Элементы списков указываются в квадратных скобках через запятую. Если объединить, получим:

```
inventar :: Inventar
inventar = Inventar [
  Objekt Pistolen 710.0 395.00,
  Objekt Tagebuch 450 30.99
]
```